# How to add splash screen before flutter window creation in Win32

Tags: flutter, dart, winapi, flutter-desktop

I am working on flutter desktop application and want to add small size splash screen before flutter application window appear. I am trying to do this in win32_window.cpp file. This is main.cpp file [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzPPQ.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzPPQ.png)

But don't know exactly what to do. Can anyone guide me please.

Thanks

Comment: I am sorry that I cannot construct a sample that can reproduce the problem based on your description.Could you please show [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) without private information?

Comment: Actually, I am not sure whether i have to edit win32 c++ code of desktop application or can do in dart code directly. I have provided code samples above.

Comment: If you want a separate window, currently you need to do that with Win32 code, not Dart. There wouldn't be anything Flutter-specific about the process.

Comment: I have [opened an issue](https://github.com/flutter/website/issues/5731) with Flutter requesting this documentation.  Please give it a thumbs up to give it more visibility with the Flutter team.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Hopefully will get some solution now.